# Apache on Mac OS Sierra: Illegal instruction: 4 $HTTPD

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, httpd.conf

#### Background

I followed the [instructions here](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions) to configure Apache, PHP, and MySQL on my Mac (running Sierra 10.12.4) and got everything working fine. I then used **Migration Assistant** to copy everything over to a new Mac (Mac #2) for another developer to use. On first login, I opened Chrome and visited `localhost`. I did not make any changes to Mac #2 beforehand.

#### The Problem

On Mac #2, when I visit `localhost` in Chrome, I get an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` *(This site can't be reached: localhost refused to connect)*. Some digging led me to [this Q/A on Apple Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131671/problem-accessing-localhost-on-mac-os-x-mavericks-it-was-working-fine-until-i), so I tried the following in Terminal:

- `ping 127.0.0.1` (success; i.e., "64 bytes from 127.0.0.1...")
- `ping localhost` (success)
- `ping myvirtualhost.dev` (success)

#### The Plot Thicks

I then tried to run `apachectl configtest`, which threw the following error:

- `/usr/local/bin/apachectl: line 79: 1132 Illegal instruction: 4 $HTTPD -t`

Ok, how about `sudo apachectl -k restart`? Nope, same error:

- `/usr/local/bin/apachectl: line 79: 1170 Illegal instruction: 4 $HTTPD "$@"`

Omitting the `-k` flag throws the same error, but the last characters are a bit different:

- `/usr/local/bin/apachectl: line 79: 1184 Illegal instruction: 4 $HTTPD -k $ARGV`

#### What I've Tried

I can't stop, start, restart, or really do anything with Apache. Google searching the error doesn't bring up much. I've tried restoring the `httpd.conf` from the backup I had, then restarting my computer. I checked `/etc/hosts` and it looks normal. I'm not sure what else to do.

Apache's config is messed up somehow but I'm not sure where. What should I do?

#### Other Potentially Useful Info

Running `httpd -v` in Terminal yields:

- `Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Unix)`

Typing `php -v` in Terminal yielded:

- `Illegal instruction: 4`

So I reinstalled and now `php -v` yields:

- `PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Apr  7 2017 13:12:17)`

Typing `which php` yields:

- `/usr/local/bin/php`

Comment: Can you please paste on the freshly migrated machine the output of: $ echo $PATH as I am almost sure that for some reason the PATH is not correct.

Comment: @Grigor Yosifov `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: This didn't look right so I removed my `.bash_profile` and restarted Terminal; now, the path is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` but the problem persists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case, it had to do with the php binary loaded in the 'other' conf file:

Try running:

`sudo mv /private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf /private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf-bak`

And then restart apache

If you don't have this conf file, it is most likely the php binary that is being loaded on your system that is causing the issue because the error is very similar to what I saw.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I ended up reformatting my hard drive several days ago and starting from scratch, as absolutely nothing else worked. Unfortunately, this means I'm unable to try your suggestion.

Comment: Worked for me. :D

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same scenario and problem that you mentioned. After some hacking and messing around, I was able to fix the issue you mentioned.

I believe reinstalling `httpd24` seemed to do the trick!

```
$ brew reinstall httpd24
```

---

Some other things that I had tried before reinstalling:

1. `brew upgrade`
2. Uninstalling `php56` (i had both `php56` & `php70` with the `sphp` script from the [blog post you mentioned](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions))
3. `brew doctor`